# SQL distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mariadb

I am trying to get distinct values from each column and not distinct row values.

My Query is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ac.admin_id , sc.student_id , tc.teacher_id
  from contact c
  join admin_contacts ac on ac.`contact_id` = c.id
  join student_contacts sc on sc.`contact_id`= c.`id`
  join teacher_contacts tc on tc.`contact_id`= c.`id`
 WHERE c.id = 1
```

Adding GROUP BY only gives unique values as long as I group by a single column, but then I would need to do this query 3 times and group by a different column each time.

Example: This is a representation of what I'm getting with this query. (This table does not list all 27 rows.)
Assuming each table column has 3 different id values, this gives a total of 3^3 = 27 rows

| c.admin_id | c.student_id | c.teacher_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 1 |
| 101 | 10 | 1 |
| 102 | 10 | 1 |
| 100 | 11 | 1 |
| 100 | 11 | 2 |
| 100 | 11 | 3 |
| 100 | 12 | 1 |

I want the following: It doesn't really have to show NULL, just to not give me all possible permutations but rather each value just once: in this example 9 values

This is what I want:

| c.admin_id | c.student_id | c.teacher_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | NULL | NULL |
| 101 | NULL | NULL |
| 102 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 10 | NULL |
| NULL | 11 | NULL |
| NULL | 12 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 1 |
| NULL | NULL | 2 |
| NULL | NULL | 3 |

This is also good, although I don't think it is possible:

| c.staff_id | c.student_id | c.teacher_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 1 |
| 101 | 11 | 2 |
| 102 | 12 | 3 |

The structure is as follows: one contact table, one role table each for admin, student and teacher, and 3 tables to combine the contacts to the roles (as it should be possible for each role to be assigned multiple contacts).

I am able to solve this by looping through the results and using only unique values for each column, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this and avoid looping through hundreds or thousands of results. (Imagine one contact represents dozens of people like an agent or similar.)

Source data:

Contact table

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "foo" | "foo@whate.ver" |

admin table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | foo |
| 101 | bar |
| 102 | bla |

student table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | foo |
| 11 | bar |
| 12 | bla |

teacher table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo |
| 2 | bar |
| 3 | bla |

admin_contacts table

| id | contact_id | admin_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 101 |
| 3 | 1 | 102 |

student_contacts table

| id | contact_id | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | 1 | 12 |

teacher_contacts table

| id | contact_id | teacher_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

Comment: It would help if you published representative source data as text.

Comment: Desired output without the source data is pretty meaningless.

Comment: Looks like you want to get 3 columns from 3 different tables, based one parent table contact, these 3 columns don't have any relation other than all these three columns are referenced in contact table. Is that correct?

Comment: First alternative: Do UNION, one select for each column.

Comment: @jarlh a UNION gives all the ids but under one label, so I can't know which table does the id belong to

Comment: select c1, null, null ... UNION select null, c2, null...

Comment: @jarlh It's almost there, the values are at the right place, the only issue now is that two columns have the name NULL. It looks like this:

| c.admin_id | NULL | NULL |

Comment: select c1 as c1, null as c2, null as c3 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to get distinct values from the set, use DISTINCT. No need to join all the tables if there are no common columns. Use UNION to combine the result sets.

This would the query that will give you the desired result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ac.admin_id , NULL, NULL 
FROM contact c
  JOIN admin_contacts ac ON ac.contact_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT NULL ,sc.student_id, NULL 
FROM contact c
  JOIN student_contacts sc ON sc.contact_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT NULL, NULL, tc.teacher_id
FROM contact c
  JOIN teacher_contacts tc ON tc.contact_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 1
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CN-AU3bN).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @jarlh for the hint

I solved it by using UNION and GROUP BY.
The query looks like this:

```
    SELECT ac.admin_id , sc.student_id , tc.teacher_id from contact c
join admin_contacts ac on ac.`contact_id` = c.id
join student_contacts sc on sc.`contact_id`= c.`id`
join teacher_contacts tc on tc.`contact_id`= c.`id`
WHERE c.id = 1
GROUP BY ac.admin_id
    UNION SELECT NULL, sc.student_id, NULL FROM contact c
join student_contacts sc on sc.`contact_id`= c.`id`
WHERE c.id = 1
    UNION SELECT NULL, NULL, tc.teacher_id FROM contact c
join teacher_contacts tc on tc.`contact_id`= c.`id`
WHERE c.id = 1
```

This gives the following results which I'm okay with

| c.admin_id | c.student_id | c.teacher_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 1 |
| 101 | 10 | 1 |
| 102 | 10 | 1 |
| NULL | 10 | NULL |
| NULL | 11 | NULL |
| NULL | 12 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 1 |
| NULL | NULL | 2 |
| NULL | NULL | 3 |

Comment: why not just do what you asked for, make the first select `select ac.admin_id, NULL, NULL from contact c join admin_contacts ac on ac.contact_id = c.id...`.  as is your query will fail with the highly recommended ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode enabled, since if there were multiple sc or tc rows it will have to chose an arbitrary one of the values to return.

Comment: Because I didn't know how I could give a name to the column and not leave it be null, and that query gave me a named column. But now I'm using the accepted answer, not this one

Comment: oh, right, it should be `select ac.admin_id, NULL student_id, NULL teacher_id from...`

Answer (score 1):

To get your first result you could union then join back to `contacts`. Note that `UNION ALL` is more efficient than `UNION`.

```sql
SELECT
  t.admin_id,
  t.student_id,
  t.teacher_id
from contact c
join (
    select ac.contact_id, ac.admin_id, null as student_id, null as teacher_id
    from admin_contacts ac

    union all

    select sc.contact_id, null, sc.student_id, null
    from student_contacts sc

    union all

    select tc.contact_id, null, null, tc.teacher_id
    from teacher_contacts tc
) t on t.contact_id = c.contact_id
WHERE c.id = 1;
```

For the second result you can join on `ROW_NUMBER`

```sql
SELECT
  ac.admin_id,
  sc.student_id,
  tc.teacher_id
from contact c
left join (
    select *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ac.contact_id ORDER BY ac.admin_id) as rn
    from admin_contacts ac
) ac on ac.`contact_id` = c.id
left join (
    select *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sc.contact_id ORDER BY sc.student_id) as rn
    from student_contacts sc
) sc on sc.`contact_id` = c.`id` and sc.rn = ac.rn
left join (
    select *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tc.contact_id ORDER BY tc.admin_id) as rn
    from teacher_contacts tc
) tc on tc.`contact_id` = c.`id` and tc.rn = ac.rn
WHERE c.id = 1;
```

Comment: the 2nd query is harder to read but works great

Comment: I just tried the first one to see if it's faster and it doesn't work, it throws unknown column c.id

Comment: Sorry copy-paste error